# Node Js Unite Testing Framework

Tags: node.js

I am working on Node Js web application and I want to unit test my application. Can anyone know about unit testing framework in Node Js which developer mostly used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `Jasmine` for a payment solution project

Answer (score 0):

Mocha and supertest are most used packages.
mocha https://mochajs.org/
supertest https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest